# Accessing third element in triple tuple

Tags: haskell, tuples

I'm looking to access the 3rd element in a Haskell tuple. The tuple is of type (String, String, Int) and I want the Int. I've tried creating my own in ways I've seen online, mainly:

```
get3rd (_,_,x) = x
```

*I've also tried using a type declaration: (String, String, Int) -> Int and by creating a custom type for the tuple and using that.

This works if the tuple I input is all made up of integers, but once I put the strings in I get this error:  Data constructor not in scope: Mary :: String
*Mary is an arbitrary String, I get an error for both strings inputted. Any help would be great on solving this!

Comment: This works, so the error is probably in code that you didn't show us. What is `Mary` ?

Comment: Did you type `(Mary, Mary, 1)` instead of `("Mary", "Mary", 1)` ?

Comment: `get3rd ("Mary", "Mary", 1)` works fine here both with `get3rd :: (String, String, Int) -> Int` and also with inferred type (`get3rd :: (t, t1, t2) -> t2`) (and so it should :) ). So, if you still have issues, you probably have to provide us with a minimal working example (i.e. full contents of a `.hs` file with a `main :: IO ()`, that does not compile for you).

Comment: Just wanted to add that generally if you find yourself using >2 element tuples, it might be worth creating a new data type.

Comment: Could you post the complete code, please?

Comment: Variable names cannot start with a capital letter. Haskell interprets those as constructors, types or typeclasses. try renaming `Mary` to `mary`

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to do it often, this

```
let (_,_,x) = someTuple
in doSomething x
```

or this

```
doSomething x
where (_,_,x) = someTuple
```

is pretty much equivalent to this

```
get3rd (_,_,x) = x
...
doSomething (get3rd someTuple)
```

but if you're dealing with something like nested tuples, it might get messy

Comment: Right, but I doubt it's clear to someone at the level of this question what you mean.